# How does $( document ).ready() work?

Tags: jasmine, jquery

I have started using jQuery and jasmine to automate webpage testing.

From what I understand, by calling `$( document ).ready()` would make sure that a webpage would finish loading.

But for the webpage I am testing, after `$( document ).ready()` returns, the background image of the webpage is still not loaded.

Did I mis-interpretate the definition and purpose of `$( document ).ready()`?

Comment: What front- end framework you are interacting with? like Angular or react etc?

Comment: @V.A., react is the front end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [it is stated on jQuery site](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run **once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute**. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run **once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready**.

So to get DOM ready it is not necessary to load the resources to the client. It is enough to know the meta-information of a node that would load the resource. To wait for resources to be loaded you should use `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })`.